# Counting with a button click

Tags: swift, button, count, swift2

I have an inexplicable problem in my Swift code. I am creating a simple game where you have to tab a button and with every click, the button change its position. I want to count these and the counting is working fine, but the problem is that at the first click, the button changes the (random) position to the top left corner and doesn't change the position anymore.

Here is a part of my code:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    refresh()
    clickCount()
}

    func refresh() {
    let XPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(275)) + 50)
    let YPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(517)) + 75)
    btn.center = CGPointMake(XPosition, YPosition)
}

    func clickCount() {
    btnCount = btnCount + 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(btnCount)"
} 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonElement()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    refresh()
}
```

I am looking forward that you can help me,
thanks a lot beforehand,

Nico

Comment: Auto Layout.  When you update the label, Auto Layout runs and places your button back where the constraints say it should be.  You have two options: 1) Create your button programmatically instead of creating it in the Storyboard. OR 2) Create `@IBOutlets` to the constraints that place your button horizontally and vertically and then update their `constant` property instead of changing `btn.center`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried it and it is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you code, and it will work if you do the following: 
Go to your Storyboard and click on "File Inspector", deselect "Use Size Classes" and "Use Auto Layout".